# Emitting Data from Javascript to qt

Tags: qt4.8

How to get the data from the Java script to qt?

In HTML page we are giving the input values and in JS file we written some calculation, its output is been display in the HTML. Now, we want to send the output we got in the calculation to the qt C++ file or QML file.

Comment: have you tried some thing??

Comment: I display the HTML page in my Qt program.

Comment: i created  the html project and linked its link to qt project . in the html page m giving the input for a calculation. the formals are written in  the js file. now i want to get the value which is been calculated from the input values to qt .